# AdMob showing properly in Navigation Drawer layout

Tags: android, admob, navigation-drawer

i have a navigation drawer layout with admob ads like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView" 
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     ads:adUnitId="11111"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In one of my fragment i have a listview, the problem is that adView shows over the listview at bottom, how can i fix that? I would like that adView would take its space.
(image link to show situation: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ci5bs67z55d247m/Screenshot_2014-09-13-10-55-38.png?dl=0).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Just move the AdView outside of the DrawerLayout nd change the DrawerLayout so that it shares the height with the AdView instead of consuming it all.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/outer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
   >
   ...
   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView" 
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3875318646278278/2314532545"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How can i do that? I can not set drawer layout height to wrap_content because it raises an exception

Comment: What error are you getting? Use a LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout and set layout_weight="1" for your DrawerLayout.

Comment: with this layout i get this result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdkh9bim2teaiz5/Screenshot_2014-09-14-23-48-29.png?dl=0

Comment: It seems as if the AdView is taking away the click event of the Navigation Drawer, when it's placed inside DrawerLayout. For me the solution was to wrap the DrawerLayout and everything inside into a RelativeLayout and keep the AdView outside of DrawerLayout, but inside the RealtiveLayout. Doing this you can also place the AdView using alignParentBottom=true, which suits my requirements.

Comment: @RuNaWaY87 I have this problem, Google disabled my ads because NavigationDrawer was over AdView (Admob), how did you fix this?